# Remove Python from usr/local/bin - 2 versions installed

Tags: python, ubuntu

Somehow i have 2 versions of Python 2 installed. The one installed in usr/local/bin is Python 2.7.13 and the one in usr/bin is Python 2.7.6 - i want to keep the 2.6 version and remove the other one.

How do i remove the other one safely ?

Output of `which python`
`/usr/local/bin/python`

Also, the symlink points to python2.7 in the usr/local/bin itself.

EDIT: The other version is not 2.6 but 2.7.6, which should be the default version installed.

Comment: **be careful!** ubuntu  heavily relies on its original python version. do not remove the one that was installed originally. you risk messing `apt` and (depending on your ubuntu version) `upstart` and other things. in the worst case you may not be able to boot into your system anymore. and: 2 python versions can happily coexist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default python version on your server is python2.7. If you remove it, you will break your system. Some apps use python2.7 to work.

If you really need to keep python2.6 (old python script for example), just specify the path to python2.6 when executing a script :

```
/usr/bin/python2.6 some_old_script.py
```

You can create virtualenv too :

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.6 my_venv
cd my_venv
source bin/activate
```

Now your venv is active, if you run :

```
python some_old_script.py
```

The script will be run in python2.6

To exit the venv :

```
deactivate
```

**EDIT**

Using multiple python versions on the same system is not a problem. It's  oftenly required (python2.6, 2.7, 3 etc.)

If by mistake you installed multiple python versions (in our case python2.7.6 and python2.7.13), you can use aliases to point to the version you want to use by default :

```
alias python=/your/python/path/python2.7.6
```

Comment: This is better advice than deleting python. +1

Comment: sorry - edited. its actually 2.7.6 which should be default. Also, i did delete python2 which deleted a lot of packages including the ubuntu-desktop. Installed some packages later though. I probably installed python twice next from separate sources.

Comment: so is there a way to delete the other 2.7 version - 2.7.13 one (the one in usr/local/bin)

Comment: @Ankit the default version is python2.7.13, you definetly should not remove it.

Comment: @Ankit btw installing mutilple python version is not problem.

Comment: @NabIlovich as far as i know, the one installed in **/usr/bin** (here 2.7.6) is the default one - also, i had installed python2.7.13 separately (was a mistake - realized later)

Comment: I don't have problems with multiple versions - may be i can just manage by making python in **/usr/bin** as the default one - so won't remove it then

Comment: @Ankit If my answer helped you, please accept it :)

Comment: @NabIlovich I am now going with the following solution - no removal of any version - just changing the default python to the one in **usr/bin/** by using alias - just edit your answer so that whatever we discussed in the comments is covered - i will accept it. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147905/discussion-between-nab-ilovich-and-ankit).